# Review audit giving contradictory results

Tags: bug, review-queues, triage

One of the review audit I just passed gave me contradictory results : the top said 'You passed' while the bottom said 'Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully'

It looks like a bug to me
[image]

Comment: That is by design, some audits get that spam warning to trick mindless reviewers. You're not one of them. That you notice this sets you apart from the rest.

Comment: Would that mean that, reading that warning, some people will automatically flag the question as spam? Wow, you can check if it's spam way easily in the second you have to wait before you are able to click any of the buttons...